# Removing nodes from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, c99

This is my second iteration of a function to remove all nodes containing value 'x'.  The previous iteration is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/237033/4203).

This function takes as input the head of a list and has to delete all the nodes that contain a given value taken.  Is this an improvement on the previous iteration?  Is there anything else that can be improved?

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;
```

```
node_t *rimuovi(node_t *head, int x){

    node_t *temp = head;
    node_t *curr = head;

    if (head == NULL){
        printf("Lista vuota, finito!\n");
        return head;
    }

    while(head->val == x){
        if (head->next == NULL){
            free(head);
            printf("La lista adesso e' vuota. Finito\n");
            return head;
        }
        else {
            curr = head->next;
            free(head);
            head = curr;
        }
    }

    temp = head;
    curr = temp->next;

    while (curr != NULL){
        if (curr->val == x){
            if(curr->next != NULL){
                temp->next = curr->next;
                free (curr);
                curr = temp->next; 
            }
            else {
                temp->next = NULL;
            }
        }
        else {
            temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: This looks like the code version before you modified it.

Comment: yes cause they said me to post a new post not to modify the original one

Comment: The suggestion was that you ask a new question with the *new* version of your code.  That way you can get feedback on the new version, without making the previous question confusing.  I've edited your question to reflect a request for a followup review.  If it doesn't match what you're looking for, please revert the change.

Answer (score 2):

**Bug: Returning a free'd pointer!**

After freeing a pointer, do not use it.

```
        free(head);
        printf("La lista adesso e' vuota. Finito\n");
        // return head;
        return NULL;
```

---

> Is there anything else that can be improved?

Rather than 2 or 3 cases to handle an empty list, list of only matches or mixed list, consider a code simplification.

Create a temporary pre-head node and assign its next to the head.  Only 1 case  needed.  This approach is reasonable when `node_t` is not large.

Some untested code.

```
node_t *rimuovi(node_t *head, int x) {
  node_t pre_head;
  node_t *p = &pre_head;
  pre_head.next = head;  // Other members are not used.

  while (p->next) {
    if (p->next->val == x) {
      node_t *next = p->next->next;
      free(p->next);
      p->next = next;
    } else {
      p = p->next;
    }
  }
  return pre_head.next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include the necessary headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

There's a lot of duplication between these branches:

> ```
> while(head->val == x){
>     if (head->next == NULL){
>         free(head);
>         printf("La lista adesso e' vuota. Finito\n");
>         return head;
>     }
>     else {
>         curr = head->next;
>         free(head);
>         head = curr;
>     }
> }
> ```

We always `free(head)`, and we probably ought to set `head = NULL` in the first branch, rather than leaving it pointing to freed memory.
Therefore:

```
while (head->val == x) {
    curr = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = curr;
    if (curr == NULL){
        printf("La lista adesso e' vuota. Finito\n");
        return head;
    }
}
```

As [chux says](/a/237103/75307), use of a dummy head node can help us merge this with the following (non-head) logic.